# Codeigniter - how to pass and overwrite a variable using $data[]

Tags: codeigniter

I've honestly been looking for ages and can't find out what it is i'm doing wrong.

Goal: Pass down a variable and update it

1. I want to declare an application wide default page title:

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

```
public $data = [];

function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();

    $this->data['pageTitle'] = 'deault';

}
```

}

2. Then I want to overwritte it per the controller being used:

class Post extends MY_Controller {

```
public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();

    $this->data['pageTitle'] = 'Posts';

}
```

}

3. And finnally declare it's name in the function of the controller:

   public function show() {

   ```
   //get global data
   $data = $this->data;

   $this->data['pageTitle'] = 'My page title';

   $this->load->view('view1', $data);
   ```

   }

End result I wish = "My page title"

End result I get = "default"

Please give a constructive answer so I can learn what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for error seems to be that you're changing `$this->data` but sending `$data` to the view.
**Possible solution 1** (You'd want to use this one)

```
public function show() {

    //get global data
    $data = $this->data;

    $data['pageTitle'] = 'My page title';  //change $data array 

    $this->load->view('view1', $data);  // send $data
}
```

**Possible solution 2**

```
public function show() {

    //get global data
    $data = $this->data;

    $this->data['pageTitle'] = 'My page title';  //change $data array 

    $this->load->view('view1', $this->data);  // send $this->data
}
```

> **Result (View)**
>
> ```
> <?php echo $pageTitle; ?> // returns 'My page title'
> ```

Hope it helps you.